# Replacing Title Attribute With Spans For ToolTips A Bad Idea For SEO?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, attributes, seo

I am currently implementing pure CSS for tool tips and started rethinking it.

I had decided to use a pure CSS approach to keep the code to text ratio down to a minimum, have better control how they are displayed and better UX. But using a pure CSS solution without any JavaScript requires removing the title attribute from the anchor tag.  **This obviously could have a disadvantage(?).**

That got me thinking: *Has the SE's evolved to look at the span tag within anchor tags in lieu of the title attribute?*

By removing the title attribute prevents the browser from displaying it's default behavior of a tool tip ( so there isn't two tool tips displayed to the user when using pure CSS) **but the title attribute is important to search engines and SEO**.

Knowing that the search engines are getting smarter and smarter by the day and I see a lot of tool tip design use implemented in this way thru the property inspector.

So:

1. **Should I still include the title attribute?** - *I see good & bad*
2. **Would there be a penalty by having a span and title containing the same text within a given anchor?** - *this would be bad*
3. **Is the span tag counted as text even-thou it's within anchors?** *Cool if it is but most likely yes*
4. **If the title attribute is omitted, would the span take its place?** *Even better to make the inter-webs a better & faster place but most likely not*

Having both would end up increasing the file size and the code ratio would increase too. It would be awesome if the SE's could search for the span tag between anchors as a title description.

So I ask you based on any current (or insider) knowledge and what I ask above, what code snippet below would be bad or best for SEO?

**The old school way with JS and/or CSS:**

```
<a class="[add my tooltip and remove the browsers]" href="#" title="description of link">The Link</a>
```

or

**A movement I have seen many developers using:**

```
<a href="#">The Link<span>description of link</span></a>
```

or

**BUt should it be:**

```
<a href="#" title"description of link">The Link<span>description of link</span></a>
```

Obviously there are a lot of factors to SEO weight to consider too so I would like to se everyone's opinion to be as thorough as possible - There might be something for every one to learn from this(?).

Thnx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
<a href="#" title="description of link">The Link<span>description of link</span></a>
```

is always advantageous, Search engines (mainly Google) are interested in the content of the link and thus the href title plays a vital role. Not only does it communicate to the user the link details but also enables SEs to read your link using its attributes and not having to follow the link to categorise.

SE robot's reading of spans is still controversial, but the title attribute is a sure thing.

Answer (score -1):

Why not try something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function (e) {

        $(".ToolTipClass").click(function (e) {
            ConfirmOK("ToolTip", $(this).prop("alt"));
        });

        function ConfirmOK(Title, Message) {
            $('<div style="padding:10px;max-width:500px;word-wrap:break-word;">' + Message + '</div>').dialog({
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: Title,
                minHeight: 75,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Stick the above code in your masterpage's document.ready event handler, then all you need to use it is set the class of anything to 'ToolTipClass' and set its alt property to whatever text you want to display in your dialog box.

You can use this code on anything, but I prefer to use "info" icons, since they're universally recognizeable.  The amount of code required for this is very minimal - and you still have the title attribute freed up for your SEO concerns.